# Commit to jenkins docker image does not save changes

Tags: jenkins, docker

I pull the official Jenkins docker image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/).
From Jenkins UI I create a new job , install the github plugin and set the repo urls in the job configuration.

Finally I save the changes from Jenkins.

I want to create a new image as it is. I stop the container, and commit it to a new image.

Then I start a new container from the new image...and Jenkins does not contain any of my changes.

I use `Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) declares the jenkins home directory as a [volume](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/02721aab9775f4f26fb23cbf204d1eb5b23d07ea/Dockerfile#L15)

```
# Jenkins home directoy is a volume, so configuration and build history 
# can be persisted and survive image upgrades
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home
```

This means all changes to the Jenkins configuration is made outside of the docker image.

## Update

The project README describes how to create your own derivative docker images with plugins pre-installed.

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

For example

```
FROM jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

Comment: Right...so I must create my own image based on the official one. Thanks

Comment: I was wondering...if I removed the VOLUME directive from the official Jenkins dockerfile , and made my changes in a new container, then I could commit it as a new image that would contain the changes...right?

Comment: Confirmed.I did it like this and now I have a Jenkins image containing a custom job and the github plugin by default.

Comment: @KostasDemiris Awesome. Was just looking for that !

Comment: @KostasDemiris How did you remove the Volume directive from the Dockerfile, can you please tell? I mean, how can I get the Dockerfile of the official Jenkins image?